# Import values (which are interconnected) from external file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I was given a Python file in which around 100 variables are defined. I do not want to put all the variables into the main file. I made a program that simulates the problem is stated below.

I have three files (two .py and one .txt). One .py file in which a global variable (`i_data`) is defined, together with a global variable (`p`) which is dependent on variable `i_data`. The value for `i_data` stated there is an initial value (which is needed to calculate `p` the first time). In this file, we made a definition in which the global variable (`i_data`) is changed to match the current value in the main (`i_main`).
The file looks like this(testdata.py):

```
    i_data = 1.
    p = i_data

    def change(i_main):
        global i_data
        i_data = i_main
        print "i_inside = " +str(i_data)
```

The second file takes a value of `i_main` from a txt file and calls the function `change` to change `i_data` to match `i_main`.

This file looks like this(testmain.py):

```
    from testdata import *
    from numpy import *

    def main():
        data = loadtxt('file.txt')  #load the data
        for j in range(3):
            i_main = data[j]        #changing i_main to match the data
            change(i_main)          #changing i_data to i_main
            print "p = " +str(p)    #p should equal i_data, which should equal i_main. So I want p=i_main
            print "i_main = " +str(i_main)
            print "i_data = " +str(i_data)
    main()
```

the txt file looks like this(file.txt):

```
1
2
3
```

I want the program to print the changed values of `i_main`, `i_data` and `p`.
Like this:

```
    i_inside = 1.0
    p = 1.0
    i_main = 1.0
    i_data = 1.0
    i_inside = 2.0
    p = 2.0
    i_main = 2.0
    i_data = 2.0
    i_inside = 3.0
    p = 3.0
    i_main = 3.0
    i_data = 3.0
```

Instead it prints this:

```
    i_inside = 1.0
    p = 1.0
    i_main = 1.0
    i_data = 1.0
    i_inside = 2.0
    p = 1.0
    i_main = 2.0
    i_data = 1.0
    i_inside = 3.0
    p = 1.0
    i_main = 3.0
    i_data = 1.0
```

How can I get the program to give the wanted result? Preferably without moving (all) variables to the main file. The global variable `i_data` should change every time `change()` is called from the file testmain.py.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?  You explained how you are doing it, but what is the final goal here?  And what sort of "file" are you talking about?  A python script, a data file, both?  There shouldn't be large data files inside a python script.

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? This is almost certainly not the best approach to whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Thanks for the feedback, I changed the example. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

In python, integers and floats are immutable.  So when you do `p = i_data`, `p` and `i_data` refer to the same data.  However, when you do `i_data = i_main`, you are changing the `i_data` so it points to the same data as `i_main`, not the data that `p` is pointing to.  So when you change `i_data`, you are no longer changing `p`.

```
i_data = 1.  % set the name i_data to refer to the data holding the value 1.
p = i_data  % set the name p to refer to the data holding the value 1.

i_main = 5.   % set the name i_main to refer to the data holding the value 5.
i_data = i_main  % set the name i_data to refer to the data holding the value 5.
```

The only way you could make this work as intended is to make `p` and `i_data` mutable data types like lists, and then change the value inside of `i_data`, like `i_data[0] = i_main`.